# What is the difference between SAP HANA, S/4HANA and HANA Cloud Platform?

Tags: hana, sap-cloud-platform, sap-basis, s4hana

What is the difference between SAP HANA, S/4HANA and HANA Cloud Platform?

Can anyone explain?

regards,

Umar Abdullah

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question. Consider asking on [SAP Community](https://community.sap.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are services and software from [SAP SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_SE):

- HANA is a database that you can use instead of MsSQL, Oracle or DB2 in your systems
- S/4 is the incompatible successor of [ECC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_ERP) (itself the successor of [R/3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_R/3)), the main ERP product of SAP. It only runs on HANA, while R/3 worked with ASE, DB2, MaxDB, MsSQL, or Oracle.

  - New data model, for example in Financials table ACDOCA replaces COEP, COBK, ANEK, ANEP, ANEA and several other tables
  - Some less used modules are removed, some are added
  - There are other smaller differences, like `matnr` field becoming 40 characters instead of 18
- HANA Cloud Platform is the HANA specific part of [SAP Cloud Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_Cloud_Platform)

Comment: "HANA Cloud Platform is the HANA specific part of SAP Cloud Platform" --> SAP just renamed _SAP HANA Cloud Platform_ (HCP) to _SAP Cloud Platform_ (SCP). It's not "a part of" SCP.

Answer (score 2):

> There are other smaller differences

I strongly disagree in that point with Andras. S/4 have dogmatic, major, **significant** differences over ECC which makes it almost a new product. Among others:

1. Completely new [Fiori](https://www.cubeserv.com/dateizentrale/dateiverwaltung/05_tool_portfolio/sap_fiori/sap_fiori_2.png) interface for apps
2. A bunch of modules were removed or merged. E.g. WM, LIS were removed in favor of EWM, CO was merged into FI (`ACDOCA` table), Foreign Trade was removed in favor of GTS and much more.
3. Several modules were completely rewritten, e.g. Finance instead of FI with completely new tables
4. All aggregations/calculations now done in CDS views
5. Completely new data model, i.e. new tables

And this is not a full list. More materials here:

https://blogs.sap.com/2018/06/25/sap-finance-sub-module-comparison-from-ecc-to-s4-hana/
https://blogs.sap.com/2016/05/16/s4-hana-and-its-differences-with-ecc/
https://blogs.sap.com/2015/11/06/architecture-of-s4-hana/
https://blogs.sap.com/2016/04/25/planning-your-jouney-to-sap-s4hana/
https://blogs.sap.com/2018/08/10/sap-controlling-co-sub-modules-comparison-from-ecc-to-s4-hana/

Comment: R/3 and S/4 are different products with differences in their functional details (Fiori does exist in R/3 too), but they are both ERP systems and one is the successor of the other. In the very general scope this question was asked, I'd say differences are small enough to not matter in this context.

Comment: `I’d say differences are small enough to not matter in this context` yes they **do** matter. This is a typical “broad” question and there is no particular context here. This statement is simply misleading

Comment: And also you make contradictory statements: firstly you write that ECC (R/3 is dead btw) and S/4 are different products and then “one is the successor of the other”.  S/4 is not a different product, it’s a [logical replacement of ECC in SAP Business Suite](https://news.sap.com/2015/03/what-is-sap-s4hana-13-questions-answered)

Comment: S4 _is_ a different product, it breaks compatibility, as you write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

SAP has invested heavily in HANA and S / 4 HANA products and has created quite a few interesting products lately even though customers now seem confused by the possibility of having so many choices available.

It is also difficult to choose the most suitable product for your company

It is important to understand what different options we now have with respect to cloud / on premise deployments and how S / 4 HANA will impact your business investment.

The purpose of this article is to try to provide you with details on the basic SAP products that are on the market today.

Below we see the main SAP products in circulation on the market:
[Tutorial: SAP HANA/S4 HANA Products Available on The Market](https://sapprofession.com/tutorial-il-punto-sui-prodotti-sap-hana-s4-hana-disponibili/)

Comment: The link is in spanish, can you please edit your answer and post your answer here ?